# Efficient way to search a list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

I have the current list of dictionaries that look like this:

```
  x =[{u'id': 813, u'overlap': 1.0},
      {u'id': 811, u'overlap': 0.002175817439439302},
      {u'id': 812, u'overlap': 0.012271742728263339},
      {u'id': 814, u'overlap': 0.9182077233294997},
      {u'id': 815, u'overlap': 0.8866809411969082},
      {u'id': 117, u'overlap': 0.9173796235219325},
      {u'id': 816, u'overlap': 0.9460961805523018},
      {u'id': 116, u'overlap': 0.2038311249297872},
      {u'id': 817, u'overlap': 0.7302323133830623},
      {u'id': 818, u'overlap': 0.81532953091762},
      {u'id': 819, u'overlap': 0.2817392052504116},
      {u'id': 820, u'overlap': 0.7905202140586483},
      {u'id': 821, u'overlap': 0.8497466449368322},
      {u'id': 822, u'overlap': 0.8503886863531487},
      {u'id': 823, u'overlap': 1.0}]
```

and I want to find for example the overlap of id==820 which is 0.7905202140586483

how can I do it efficiently and elegantly in very few lines of python code? (I will loop over millions of such arrays).

Comment: No such way for a list - a list, by definition, is searched sequentially unless you separately maintain some kind of index. Why not change this into a dictionary?

Comment: I read it from Mongodb as such. Can I easily transform it into dictionaries where ids are the keys and overlap is the value?

Comment: Of course, you can. I leave it an exercise for you, the hint is: dict comprehension.

Comment: If you give the relevant parts of the code that produced the sequence (I'm interested in the classes involved), we might suggest a way to return the sequence already indexed by `id`. MongoDB appears to be capable of that.

Comment: Is there a possibility of multiple list entries that will have overlapping keys?

Comment: @Pyson No .. they are unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Efficiency depends on the situation. It's worth noting that converting it do a dict doesn't come without a cost. If you use almost all the items, convert it to a dict like suggested. If you only ever use a few items in the list, this will be more efficient:

```
d = {v['id']: v['overlap'] for v in x if v['id'] in (820, 811, 117)}
```

A small test (with the list in your question) shows that this gives a ~33% decrease in time usage if you're looking for just 2/15 items. At more than 5-6 of the 15 items it was no longer faster.

You'll have to test yourself how this scales to larger lists (you can use `timeit.timeit` for that). If you are able to create a dict *instead* of a list, go for it. Otherwise, if this is a performance-critical part of your application, do some tests and see what works best for your situation.

Comment: This is great! I actually use two items at most and this worked perfectly!

Comment: I don't know how you're seeing this as faster? Even for small numbers (2-3) of items, just building the entire dict seems marginally faster, probably because of the lack of comparisons. The only time that this approach might be better is if the list of dicts is enormous, so you can avoid copying the whole thing. And in that sort of case, you probably want to switch to something more scalable like a Pandas DataFrame.

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi That's what both of [these](http://pastebin.com/CnnCTAAY) [two](http://pastebin.com/RvAvu8hn) tests say, quite consistently. Now I'm no expert on profiling and optimizing, so let me know if there's anything wrong with these tests, but it seems to me this method _is_ faster for getting 2 items out of a 15 item list, at least on my machine. If you wan't to know why, you'll need to analyse the generated bytecode.

Comment: Thanks for the remark @Chinmay The list is big (on average 500,000 items). this has been working fine for me!

Answer (score 4):

Because each dictionary only has two values (an 'id' and an 'overlap'), I would suggest that you try converting the whole thing into one large dictionary, and then go from there.  Something like:

```
x_dict = {entry['id']: entry['overlap'] for entry in x}
```

Then you can get the value you want with a call to .get():

```
x_dict.get(id)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
x2 = {d["id"]:d["overlap"] for d in x}
print x2[820]
```

as mentioned in the comments use a dict

or query from mongo where `id=820` (not sure offhand how.. only used mongo a handful of times)

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows using dictionary comprehension:

```
a_dict = {v['id']: v['overlap'] for v in x};
```

This results in:

```
for id,overlap in a_dict.items():
    print(id, overlap)

# output

811 0.002175817439439302
812 0.012271742728263339
813 1.0
814 0.9182077233294997
815 0.8866809411969082
816 0.9460961805523018
817 0.7302323133830623
818 0.81532953091762
819 0.2817392052504116
116 0.2038311249297872
117 0.9173796235219325
822 0.8503886863531487
823 1.0
820 0.7905202140586483
821 0.8497466449368322
```